# CMake (C++): Link one project to another, already built, project or library

Tags: c++, cmake, clang

Hi I am relatively new to using CMake and recently took over a C++ project with the following file system setup:

```
MyProject
|- proj_folder1 (functionality)
|---- files/subdirectories
|-----CMakeLists
|- proj_folder2 (functionality)
|---- files/subdirectories
|-----CMakeLists
|- proj_folder3 (functionality)
|---- files/subdirectories
|-----CMakeLists
|- 3rd_party_dependencies
|---- Subdirectories for various dependencies (googletest, abseil-cpp, simdjson, etc)
|---- CMakeLists
|- CMakeLists
```

**Some things to note:**

At the top level of my project, apart from setting various flags and env variables, the CMakeLists.txt file includes the following, which are the only references to the subdirectories in the project within this file:

```
add_subdirectory(3rd_party_dependencies)
add_subdirectory(proj_folder1)
add_subdirectory(proj_folder2)
add_subdirectory(proj_folder3)
```

Inside the 3rd party dependencies directory, the root CMakeLists just includes a number of `add_subdirectory()` calls for its dependencies (e.g. `add_subdirectory(libhv))`. I have not touched any of the files in the directories for these dependencies, and because I'm using various 3rd party libraries and projects, there's no set pattern for how they're built, compiled, or linked. However, at the moment, the CMakeLists in my project directories ensure that everything within my project works and is linked to the proper dependencies.

Also worth noting, I'm using the Ninja build tool to run my project.

**My Question:**

Because these 3rd party dependencies change so infrequently, I've been asked to modify my project such that all these 3rd party dependencies are built separately from the rest of my project. I'm supposed to store these artifacts in a location accessible from anywhere in the server and then modify my project so that whenever I compile my project, it finds the artifacts for all my 3rd party dependencies and links against them. I've been scouring forums and wikis but I'm pretty lost and haven't been able to find anything helpful describing how to link two separately built c++ projects. Could anyone provide any insight as to how this can be achieved? Thanks in advance!

---

I built my third party dependencies to another location on my server using the following command from the root of my project directory:

`cmake -GNinja -B /location_to_store_artifacts ./3rd_party_dependencies`

This successfully created the build artifacts along with CMakeCache.txt, cmake_install.cmake, and compile_commands.json files. Thus far I haven't made any progress beyond this because I've exclusively been trying to research cmake and none of the pages or blog posts I've seen have been related to my situation.

Comment: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) is what you want to concern yourself with to get a target to link to a library and / or library dependency. The folder structure is not as important. CMake lets you use the folder structure that you want.

Comment: Given the fact that my project's CMakeLists.txt doesn't have a command like add_executable() or add_library() and the 3rd party dependencies don't create a shared library file, what changes would I have to make (in as specific or as broad terms as you'd like)?

Comment: ***Given the fact that my project's CMakeLists.txt doesn't have a command like add_executable() or add_library()*** I expected both your project and the 3rd_party_dependencies to have several of each of those. I guess I don't understand your unusual project type.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need imported targets:

```
add_library(foo STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY
             IMPORTED_LOCATION "/path/to/libfoo.a")
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html

Answer (score 0):

CMake has utilities to build, export, install and import targets. Usually the 3rd party libraries do something like (using the GLFW project as an example here):

```
install(TARGETS glfw
EXPORT glfwTargets
RUNTIME DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}"
ARCHIVE DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}"
LIBRARY DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}")
```

This allows the GLFW project to export its targets for inclusion in other projects. Software packagers also use this as a way to package the software for distribution.
Header-only libraries can also do this export, even if they don't produce any binary files for linking.

Straight forward option within your project is to the use the generated `.cmake` *target import files* from these 3rd party dependencies once they are *installed* via `cmake --install <binarydir> --install-prefix <installprefix>`.

The generated *target import files* provide more than just a path to the library files: `include()` the installed `.cmake` to import the exact dependency into the consumer project. The imported targets have a proper dependency graph for linking, compiler flags, and include paths already setup.

CMake `find_package()` also works with installed *target import files*, if you specify where you installed the dependency. Be warned, though, that it may ignore your hint.

What you probably want is to build and install the 3rd party dependencies into *a prefix*. There are multiple ways to archive this. Newest that I have seen is via CMake `FetchContent()`:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(googletest URL "download url")
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)
```

Internally this is using CMake `ExternalProject` module to build and install the dependency. You could also use the ExternalProject module directly to have more control over the build process and where the dependencies are installed.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.27/guide/using-dependencies/index.html#guide:Using%20Dependencies%20Guide